# Switching between 2 Views in 2 distinct View Controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a problem with transitioning between views in different `ViewController`s.

Here is the situation:

My App is a TabBarApplication done with IB which contains a `UIViewController` for each Tab. The `UIViewController` (PlayerTabViewController) of the first tab contains another `UIViewController` (PlayerCreationViewController) to manage a view that will be added as subview.

I was able to add the subview using

`[self.view addSubview:playerCreationViewController.view];`

In the PlayerTabViewController.

The problem is that from the subview I have to return to the parent view and reload it because it contains a tableview that must be refreshed.

Using `[self.view removeFromSuperview];` in the PlayerCreationViewController I can switch back to the parent view, but I'm not able to reload the tableview or do other actions.
I tried to implement the `-(void)willRemoveSubview:(UIView *)subview` method in PlayerTabViewController but it seems the function is never called.

Do you have an Idea of what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you are using wrong method to go on next view. just use navigation view controller to switch from one view to another view.

create a object of view

```
PlayerCreationViewController *playerViewController = [[PlayerCreationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayerCreationViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:playerViewController animated:YES];

[playerViewController release];
```